# Q: Deactivation of Google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

When I access the page of certain communities of Stackoverflow, it often occurs that for about a minute my computer gets a very high loading and I can't even scroll the page with the mouse. Recently I read at the bottom of the screen that it was waiting for google.analytics.com in that time period.
Is this a normal phenomenon to be expected or could I do something to avoid
that inconvenience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can opt out of being tracked by Google Analytics or download a number of add-ons that block network requests for the script, but I highly doubt that would solve your problem.

Google Analytics is loaded asynchronously, so it doesn't block other scripts or affect the performance of anything else on the page while it's being downloaded.

There may be times where the connection is slow or for whatever reason it takes a while for your browser to download the script from google-analytics.com, but if you page is responding slowly and you happen to see that it's waiting for google-analytics.com at the bottom, those two things are likely not related.

What's far more likely is that whatever is causing the request for the Google Analytics script to be slow **is also** causing the rest of the page to be slow. In other words Google Analytics is not the root of your problem, it's another symptom.

In either case, you can try blocking it just to be sure. Sometimes web developers implement Google Analytics incorrectly...

Comment: You are certainly right. For I just accessed again the page of a community of Stackoverflow (with the page of Stackoverflow itself I never have had problems) and this time at the bottom of the screen I read gravatar.com during the time I couldn't do anything with my computer..

Comment: Sorry, although I am not new in Stackoverflow, I am sofar ignorant of how to mark an answer as accepted. BTW, please be kind enough to help me understand one issue, namely why my computer gets very high loading from some organizations like gravater.com when I access the pages of certain communities of Stackoverflow instead of the page of Stackoverflow itself. (I guess such organizations are foreign to Stackoverflow.)

Comment: To answer your first question, here's how, I just Googled "How do I mark an answer as accepted on Stack Overflow": http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: For your second question, you can use the Chrome Dev Tools to see how much time is spent loading which resources: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/network

Comment: I have duly done the marking. My second question is actually mainly asking what such organizations as gravater.com have to do with the communities of Stackoverflow (since I guess that they probably are  foreign to Stackoverflow and hence, if that's indeed the case,  shouldn't intervene in the business of Stackoverflow).

Comment: That's not really related to this question, so you should ask it elsewhere. Or just Google it.